# How to align icons with their titles or text description?

Tags: html, css

My icons and texts are in different list tags. Icons aren't aligned with their titles. They are written as two unordered lists. The only solution I have right now is to merge lists to one ul, but I'm hoping there is a better way to do it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cart"></i></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Settings</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Account</li>
    <li>Cart</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use one list instead of two.

Comment: Is there a reason that You use 2 lists?

Comment: @user2624626 Yes. It is created dynamically by a plugin inside a cms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:** If you don't want icons and texts to be in same `ul` try defining fixed width for `li`s.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**Method 2:**
If you can Integrate 2 lists, that is better solution:

```
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Account</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cart"></i>Cart</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li i {
    display: block;
    /* add margins here to adjust icons */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge the icons and titles in one list.

```
<ul>
  <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Account</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-cart"></i>Cart</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The only solution I have right now is to merge lists to one ul, which I don't want to do. Because it is dynamic. I am trying to solve with css

Comment: Hey Nick, it's ok. You should have told it's dynamic earlier :) "They are written as two unordered lists."  text as `Dynamic` would have sounded better.

Answer (score 2):

I might be little late here. But try this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use one list instead of two, but if you want you can `float` both `<ul>`'s to the left. please see below:

```css
.icons{float:left;}
.names{float:left;}
```

```html
<ul class="names">
    <li>Settings</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Account</li>
    <li>Cart</li>
</ul>
<ul class="icons">
    <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>icon-setting</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>icon-home</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>icon-account</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cart"></i>icon-cart</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Manoj Kumar gave good ans but,
if need two lists then try this

```css
.left{
  float: left;
}
.clear{
 clear: left; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="left">
    <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cart"></i></li>
</ul>
<ul class="left">
    <li>Settings</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Account</li>
    <li>Cart</li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to hold in one list instead of two

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Settings</span></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Home</span></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>Account</span></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-cart"></i><span>Cart</span></li>
</ul>

<button class="toogle-menu" type="button">toogle</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.toogle-menu').click(function(){
        $('.menu li span').toogle();        // http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
    });
</script>

<style>
    .menu{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        list-style:none;
    }
    .menu li{ 
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .menu li span{ 
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    }

</style>
```